# Dynamically arrange bootstrap buttons in concentric circles with css animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-animations

I am working on this project to develop web application from an adobe xd design. Here is the link to the design [store finder design-adobe xd](https://www.uplabs.com/posts/free-psd-for-find-the-store) This is what I have done so far
 `

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
     <meta name="description" content="">
     <meta name="author" content="">
     <title>Store Finder</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" 
       href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
       integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" 
       crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Store Finder\storeFinder.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <!-- the navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
       <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
  data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" 
  aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
     <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
       <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
       <button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
     </form>
      </div>
      </nav>

     <div class="container">
     <div class="blockquote text-center card border-light mx-auto" style="max-width: 50rem;">

      <div class="headings"><!-- Headings -->
       <h3 class="card-title">SHOPS IN MALL</h3>
       <h5 class="card-text">Find the store you need quickly and easily</h5>
      </div>

     <div class="inputFields"><!-- Input search field -->
       <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by store name" aria-label="searchby 
      storename">
         <div class="input-group-append"> <!--appends the dropdowns and search button to the input 
    search field -->
            <!--dropdown buttons -->
            <div class="btn-group"><!--keeps the dropdowns together while allowing to have different 
    menu item lists -->
                <button id="categoryDropdown" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" 
    type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Choose 
    Category</button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a id="ddElectronics" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Electronics</a>
                  <a id="ddFashion" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fashion</a>
                  <a id="ddKids" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kids</a>
                  <a id="ddSports" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sports wear and accessories</a>
                  <a id="ddFood" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Food</a>
                 <!-- <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>  -->

                </div>
            </div>
   <div class="btn-group"><!--keeps the dropdowns together while allowing to have different menu 
    item lists -->
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data- 
    toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Select floor</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu floors">
              <a id="ddLg" class="dropdown-item floors" href="#">LG</a>
              <a id="ddUg" class="dropdown-item floors" href="#">UG</a>
              <a id="ddOne" class="dropdown-item floors" href="#">1</a>
              <a id="ddTwo" class="dropdown-item floors" href="#">2</a>
              <a id="ddThree" class="dropdown-item floors" href="#">3</a>
              <a id="ddFour" class="dropdown-item floors" href="#">4</a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <button type="button" id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--The big box with shadow effect containing the buttons-->
    <div id="circleContainer" class="card-body shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
    <div id="circle-buttons" class="btnDiv">

         <ul id="btnList" class="btnList"></ul>
    </div>



     </div>

     </div>
     </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
     q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Store Finder\storeFinder.js"></script>




     .btn-circle.btn-xl { 
            width: 100px; 
            height: 100px; 
            padding: 10px 16px; 
            border-radius: 50px; 
            font-size: 12px; 
            text-align: center; 
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        } 

    #circleContainer {

    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    }

    .btnList {
    list-style: none;
    }

    .btnList li {
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
     transition: all 2s ease 5s;
    }

    /*Rotate and translate the circle buttons*/
    .animate {
     animation-name: example;
     animation-duration: 5s;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards; /*stops the animation at the last frame, stops it from going 
    back to 
    the original position*/
     } 

    /*Rotate the inner html of the buttons back to the upright position*/
     .animateBtnHtml {
     animation-name: btnInnerHtml;
     animation-duration: 5s;
     animation-delay: 5s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     }

    @keyframes example{
    100% {transform: rotate(-180deg) translate(-200px,-200px);} 
    }

      @keyframes btnInnerHtml{
      100% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
      }


    //categories array definitions
    var categoryElectronics = ['Croma','Fuji','Aptronix','Joway','Miniso','Reliance Digital','Oppo Store','Wonder Chef'];
    var categoryFashion = ['American Eagle','Calvin Klien','Global Desi','Lifestyle','M&S','Maanyavar','Mebaz','Pantaloons','Tommy Hilfiger','Westside'];
    var categoryKids = ['Apple of my i','Born Babies','FBB Kids','First Cry','Gini & Jony','Mom & Me'];
    var categorySports = ['Adidas','Columbia','Fila','Nike','Reebok','Speedo','Puma','Yonex'];
    var categoryFood = ['Taco Bell','KFC','Pizza Hut','Pista House','Mc Donalds','Cream Stone','Drunken Monkey','Subway','Dominos','Burger King'];

    //floors array definition
    var floorLg = ['Spar','Fbb','Miniso','Reliance Trends','Nike','Fila','Puma','KFC','Pizza Hut','Taco Bell'];
    var floorUg = ['Mac','Lifestyle','Caretlane','Starbucks','M&S','Da Milano','Fossil','Westside','Shoppers stop','Aldo'];
    var floorOne = ['Lifestyle','Centro','Yoyoso','Max','Cafe Coffeeday','Allen solly','Van Husen','Trueblue','Basics','Bata'];
    var floorTwo = ['Home Center','Reliance Digital','Croma','Danube Home','Samsung','Super 99','Urban ladder','Bblunt','Marie claire','Cafe54'];
    var floorThree = ['Neerus','W','Aurelia','Dominos','Firstcry','Health & glow','Ritu kumar','Toy globe','One friday','Mebaz'];
    var floorFour = ['Bazaar','Hamleys','AMB','Sky zone','Karachi bakery','Food court','Tridom','Vr gaming','Scary house','Market 99'];

    //Search array definition
    var searchArr = ['AMB','Spar','Food Court','Bazaar','Lifestyle','Reliance Digital','Croma','Hamleys','Sky zone','M&S','Starbucks','Home Center','Centro','Shoppers Stop','Mayfair'];

    //on click actions for the category Electronics
    $('#ddElectronics').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
        //calling the genButtons functions for the dropdown item selected;
        genButtons(categoryElectronics);

      //adding the animate class to each button inside list item
      var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
      $.each(btns, function(i,l){

         $(l).addClass('animate'); //adding animate class to li element
        $(l).children('button').addClass('animateBtnHtml'); //adding the animateBtnHtml class to button element inside li to rotate the names.

      });

    });

    //on click actions for the category Fashion
    $('#ddFashion').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
        //calling the genButtons functions for the dropdown item selected;
        genButtons(categoryFashion);
       //adding the animate class to each button inside list item
      var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
      $.each(btns, function(i,l){

         $(l).addClass('animate'); //adding animate class to li element
        $(l).children('button').addClass('animateBtnHtml'); //adding the animateBtnHtml class to button element inside li to rotate the names.

      });
    });

    //on click actions for the category kids
    $('#ddKids').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
        //calling the genButtons functions for the dropdown item selected;
        genButtons(categoryKids);
       //adding the animate class to each button inside list item
      var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
      $.each(btns, function(i,l){

         $(l).addClass('animate'); //adding animate class to li element
        $(l).children('button').addClass('animateBtnHtml'); //adding the animateBtnHtml class to button element inside li to rotate the names.

      });
    });

    //on click actions for the category Sports
    $('#ddSports').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
        //calling the genButtons functions for the dropdown item selected;
        genButtons(categorySports);
       //adding the animate class to each button inside list item
      var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
      $.each(btns, function(i,l){

         $(l).addClass('animate'); //adding animate class to li element
        $(l).children('button').addClass('animateBtnHtml'); //adding the animateBtnHtml class to button element inside li to rotate the names.

      });
    });

    //on click actions for the category Food
    $('#ddFood').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
        //calling the genButtons functions for the dropdown item selected;
        genButtons(categoryFood);
       //adding the animate class to each button inside list item
      var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
      $.each(btns, function(i,l){

         $(l).addClass('animate'); //adding animate class to li element
        $(l).children('button').addClass('animateBtnHtml'); //adding the animateBtnHtml class to button element inside li to rotate the names.

      });

    });

    //on click actions for the category LG Floor
    $('#ddLg').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
        //calling the genButtons functions for the dropdown item selected;
        genButtons(floorLg);
       //adding the animate class to each button inside list item
      var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
      $.each(btns, function(i,l){

         $(l).addClass('animate'); //adding animate class to li element
        $(l).children('button').addClass('animateBtnHtml'); //adding the animateBtnHtml class to button element inside li to rotate the names.

      });
    });

    //on click actions for the category UG Floor
    $('#ddUg').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
        //calling the genButtons functions for the dropdown item selected;
        genButtons(floorUg);
       //adding the animate class to each button inside list item
      var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
      $.each(btns, function(i,l){

         $(l).addClass('animate'); //adding animate class to li element
        $(l).children('button').addClass('animateBtnHtml'); //adding the animateBtnHtml class to button element inside li to rotate the names.

      });       
    });

    //on click actions for the category Floor one
    $('#ddOne').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
        //calling the genButtons functions for the dropdown item selected;
        genButtons(floorOne);
       //adding the animate class to each button inside list item
      var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
      $.each(btns, function(i,l){

         $(l).addClass('animate'); //adding animate class to li element
        $(l).children('button').addClass('animateBtnHtml'); //adding the animateBtnHtml class to button element inside li to rotate the names.

      });
    });

    //on click actions for the category Floor two
    $('#ddTwo').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
        //calling the genButtons functions for the dropdown item selected;
        genButtons(floorTwo);
       //adding the animate class to each button inside list item
      var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
      $.each(btns, function(i,l){

         $(l).addClass('animate'); //adding animate class to li element
        $(l).children('button').addClass('animateBtnHtml'); //adding the animateBtnHtml class to button element inside li to rotate the names.

      });
    });

    //on click actions for the category Floor Three
    $('#ddThree').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
        //calling the genButtons functions for the dropdown item selected;
        genButtons(floorThree);
       //adding the animate class to each button inside list item
      var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
      $.each(btns, function(i,l){

         $(l).addClass('animate'); //adding animate class to li element
        $(l).children('button').addClass('animateBtnHtml'); //adding the animateBtnHtml class to button element inside li to rotate the names.

      });
    });

    //on click actions for the category Floor Four
    $('#ddFour').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor functionality
        //calling the genButtons functions for the dropdown item selected;
        genButtons(floorFour);

       //adding the animate class to each button inside list item
      var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
      $.each(btns, function(i,l){

        $(l).addClass('animate'); //adding animate class to li element
        $(l).children('button').addClass('animateBtnHtml'); //adding the animateBtnHtml class to button element inside li to rotate the names.

      });         




    });


    //Function to dynamically generate the circle buttons for the categoty selected from the dropdown menus
    var catArr;
    function genButtons(catArr)
    {

        var categoryArray = catArr;
        var totalRecords = 500; //part of dynamic button generation script
        var recordsPerPage = 50; //part of dynamic button generation script
        var className; //part of dynamic button generation script
        var totalButtons = totalRecords/recordsPerPage; //part of dynamic button generation script
        var circleButtonsDiv = document.getElementById("circle-buttons"); //part of dynamic button generation script
            console.log(totalButtons)

    var btnColors = ['btn-primary','btn-secondary','btn-success','btn-danger','btn-warning','btn-light','btn-dark','btn-primary','btn-secondary','btn-success','btn-danger','btn-warning','btn-light','btn-dark','btn-primary']; //bootstrap button colors
    var btnColorLen = btnColors.length; //bootstrap button colors
            console.log("length = "+btnColorLen);   //bootstrap button colors
    var btnList = document.getElementById("btnList"); //UL 
        $('#btnList').empty();


        var arrLength = categoryArray.length;
            console.log("Length inside function = "+arrLength);



        for(var i=0; i<arrLength; i++)
        {
            var button = document.createElement("button");//creating button
            button.innerHTML = categoryArray[i]; //put store name from the array as title for the button
            //circleButtonsDiv.appendChild(button);//appending button to div

            className = "btn "+btnColors[i]+" btn-circle btn-xl";
                console.log("className = "+className);
            $(button).addClass(className);
        button.setAttribute("id","circleBtns");

        var node = document.createElement("li"); //creating a list item
        node.appendChild(button); //adding button element to list item 
        btnList.appendChild(node); //adding list item to ul


        //Event Listener for when one of the circle buttons are clicked
            button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            var btn = event.target;
            var btnName = btn.innerHTML; //get the name of the button clicked
            var btnPressed = btn.getAttribute("Clicked on "+btnName); //message to show in the alert
            circleButtonsDiv.appendChild(btn);
            alert("Clicked on "+btnName);
            // goto(page) -- write your function for getting the records for page[page]
            });

        }
        return;
    }
```

`[store finder jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vae6pgcm/1/) (currently only the drop down menus work, the search input field and button are not working right now).
I want the buttons to arrange in concentric circles like in the xd design. I could specify fixed angles but the number of buttons changes with the dropdown menu option selected. I also tried using jquery keyframes but it just did not work for me. I am not able to figure out how this can be done. Please help.

Comment: improperly formatted code!!!

Comment: @nikhil sugandh Can you please explain what you mean by improperly formatted code.